# Write and receive image to embedded modem via Txd and Rxd in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, uart, modem

How can I send and receive image (page) to embedded modem via Txd and Rxd in raspberry pi3 using Python?

And how can configure baudrate and flow control using Cts and Rts?

Comment: python has a serial library that you can use for that

Comment: Every serial library can do that. But you might want to look into a communication library instead, as (a good one) will also handle the modem for you.

Comment: My problem is when i am sendding page the remot fax receive only 3 kbyte from the image.. buode rate for serial is 19200 ...i thuoth my problem is flowcotrol ... i am using cts rts pin in pi3 ... can i help how can write python code to send image fully ?